# 24 Game with $31,41,59,26,53$ and an additional number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, card-games

We have got five numbers $31,41,59,26,53$,please add a positive integer $n$,as small as possible,which we can find a way to manipulate these numbers with addition, subtraction, multiplication, or division, so that the end result is 24.Like this:$\frac{8}{3-\frac{8}{3}}=24$.

PS:I'm so sorry to change the problem so many times,but since $53-41=12,59-26-31=2$,so we can just add $1$.

My purpose for asking this problem is to find the answer to this question:if we have $x_1,x_2,……x_k$,what's the smallest number we need add them to make 24? Such as $12,34,56,78,90,105?$

Comment: $38$ works --- $314+265-358-159-38=24$.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson:maybe 38 is the smallest.I'm going to change the numbers in the problem to make it more interesting if you don't mind.:)

Comment: $12$ works: $358-314-(265/159)*12=24.$

Comment: @coffeemath：Cool.

Comment: With the latest numbers, can get $n=2$: $(31-41+59-53+26)+2=24.$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
1\times(53-41)(59-26-31)=24
$$

In general I think this will be hard, since if we restrict to addition and subtraction it is almost the [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum).

As a heuristic, with just addition and subtraction we can make $2^k$ expressions between $-\sum x_i$ and $\sum x_i$, so on average we can make numbers spaced by about $2^{1-k}\sum x_i$ so as $k$ grows we should expect to get pretty close.

For the set $\{12,34,56,78,90,105\}$ we can add $24$ to the set, then check all partitions into $S_1,S_2$ for the smallest non-zero* $\sum_{S_1}-\sum_{S_2}$. In this case it is $90+78+34-105-56-12-24=5$, so 5 is a candidate.

For these numbers, however, we can do better, since
$$(90-56-34)(105+78)+12\times 2 =24$$
so 2 works (but I can't rule out 1).

(* Instead of including 24 and checking non-zero differences we can add 23 look for a zero solution, then repeat with 25 if necessary.)

Comment: Well, you can't get a positive integer smaller than $1$, so this looks like a winner.

Comment: Yeah,you are the winner,I'll take this answer as the accepted answer,but you can try the new numbers:12,34,56,78,90,105 if you like..